# How to generate .aar file from existing react native application

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Hi I'm a new in react native development. I need to create `*.aar` lib to be used by third party android application. How to generate `*.aar` file from it? Can you explain by steps? Has read a lot of topics but still unsuccessful.